# Gerar arquivo txt de acordo com layout pré-definido em c#

Tags: c#, arquivo, exportação

Preciso exportar dados de uma classe de acordo com um layout especifico que consiste em tamanho e posição.

Para fácil manutenção, preciso que seja simples alterar o layout.

Segue abaixo a minha classe:

```
    public class NovosCotistasDTO
    {
        public string Agencia { get; set; }
        public string Conta { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataInclusao { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public string IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    }
```

Segue abaixo Layout que deve ser exportado:

```
Campo           |Tamanho    |Posição Inicial    |Posição Final
--------------------------------------------------------------
Agencia         |5          |1                  |5
Conta           |13         |6                  |19
DataInclusao    |10         |20                 |30
Tipo            |1          |31                 |32
IdUsuario       |7          |33                 |40
CNPJ            |14         |41                 |55
```

Comment: O que você já fez?

Answer (score 4):

A biblioteca [FileHelpers](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers) faz exatamente isso que você precisa.

Com ela você pode definir layouts de arquivos por tamanho e posição.

No seu caso específico, após importar o **FileHelpers** em seu projeto, você implementaria da seguinte forma:

### Classe Definindo o Layout

***Edição da Resposta:*** é necessário utilizar campos simples em vez de properties (get / set).

```
using FileHelpers;

[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.ExactLength)]
public class NovosCotistasDTO
{
    [FieldFixedLength(5)]
    public string agencia;

    [FieldFixedLength(13)]
    public string conta;

    [FieldFixedLength(10)]
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")] // Outros formatos de data são possíveis. Ex: "DD/MM/AAAA", "ddMMyyyyHHmmss", etc.
    public DateTime dataInclusao;

    [FieldFixedLength(1)]
    public string tipo;

    [FieldFixedLength(7)]
    public string idUsuario;

    [FieldFixedLength(14)]
    public string cnpj;
}
```

### Como Gravar os Registros No Arquivo TXT

Gravar um arquivo de registros usando FileHelpers é bem simples. Você pega uma lista dos objetos que deseja salvar em arquivo e passa para o FileHelpers do seguinte modo:

```
public void EscrevaArquivo(string nomeDoArquivo, List<object> registros)
{
    FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(NovosCotistasDTO));

    engine.WriteFile(nomeDoArquivo, registros);
}
```

### Como Ler os Registros Salvos no Arquivo

Para obter de volta os registros que você salvou usando esse layout, basta fazer da seguinte forma:

```
public List<NovosCotistasDTO> LeiaArquivo(string nomeDoArquivo)
{
    var engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(NovosCotistasDTO));

    var linhasDoArquivo = engine.ReadFile(nomeDoArquivo);

    var listaDeRegistros = new List<NovosCotistasDTO>();

    foreach (var linha in linhasDoArquivo)
    {
        lista.Add((NovosCotistasDTO)linha);
    }

    return listaDeRegistros;
}
```

Comment: Muito legal essa lib. +1.

Comment: Também gosto do FileHelpers, @CiganoMorrisonMendez. Atualizei a resposta agora adicionando exemplos de como ler e como escrever arquivos usando o layout. Qualquer dúvida pode me procurar. :)

Comment: Pó meu gostei desse cara, mas não está funcionando verifiquei que o atributo "FieldFixedLength", não pode ser usado com "get" e "set". Quando estou instanciando o MultiRecordEngine(typeof(NovosCotistasDTO)); ocorre erro "An unhandled exception of type 'FileHelpers.BadUsageException' 
You only provide one type to the engine constructor. You need 2 or more types, for one type you can use the FileHelperEngine."

Comment: Estou tentando usar o FileHelperEngine e ocorre o seguinte erro "Exception of type 'FileHelpers.BadUsageException' occurred in FileHelpers.dll
The field: 'Agencia' can't be marked with FieldFixedLength attribute, it is only for the FixedLengthRecords not for delimited ones.". Aguem sabe o que estou fazendo de errado ?

Comment: @LuãGovindaMendesSouza quanto às properties, realmente o FileHelpers tem essa limitação. Vou atualizar a resposta usando campos simples em vez de properties.

Comment: @LuãGovindaMendesSouza acho que encontrei o motivo do erro. O **MultRecordEngine** serve para quando existe mais de um tipo de registro, porém como no seu caso há somente um tipo de registro (NovosCotistasDto) então tem que usar o **FileHelperEngine** nesse caso. Vou modificar a resposta, alterando a declaração da engine para **FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(NovosCotistasDto));**.  Quando você puder, por favor faz um teste para verificar se deu certo. Obrigado.

Comment: @UlyssesAlves Fiz a alteração para "FileHelperEngine" e retornou o seguinte erro "An unhandled exception of type 'FileHelpers.BadUsageException' occurred in FileHelpers.dll

Additional information: The field: 'Agencia' can't be marked with FieldFixedLength attribute, it is only for the FixedLengthRecords not for delimited ones."  Poderia ver na documentação mas aonde estou trabalhando não tenho acesso a pagina desse Helper.

Comment: @LuãGovindaMendesSouza Tente por favor colocar o atributo **[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.ExactLength)]** sobre a definição da classe do registro em *public class NovosCotistasDTO*. Atualizei a resposta novamente com mais essa alteração/correção.

Answer (score 1):

Tem várias maneiras de resolver. Uma das minhas favoritas é fazer um `override` do `ToString()`:

```
public class NovosCotistasDTO
{
    public string Agencia { get; set; }
    public string Conta { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataInclusao { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public string IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }

    public override String ToString() 
    {
        return Agencia.Replace("-", "") + 
            Conta.Replace("-", "").Replace(".", "") +
            DataInclusao.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") +
            Tipo.Substring(0, 30) +
            IdUsuario.Substring(0, 7) +
            CNPJ.Replace("-", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("/", "")
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var cotistaDto = new NovosCotistasDTO 
{
    Agencia = "1234",
    Conta = "12345-6",
    DataInclusao = DateTime.Now,
    Tipo = "Tipo",
    IdUsuario = "Usuario",
    CNPJ = "12.345.678/0001-99"
};

String layout = cotistaDto.ToString();
```

Note que essa solução é bastante simples, e o controle de caracteres é inteiramente manual.

Usando `String.Format` é possível fazer algo ainda mais sofisticado, mas é preciso entender melhor como são suas condições de dados:

- O que acontece quando um dado é maior que a máscara;
- Como os dados são atribuídos no seu DTO;
- Outras condições de validação.